# How to use FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION with the Android Storage Access Framework?

Tags: android, file, uri, saf

I want to use the Storage Access Framework (SAF) in Android to get and save in a local database the uri of a large amount of files (>600).

So to get 1 file's uri, I call:

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION
                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_FILE_OPEN)
```

then in the onActivityResult, I persist the permission granted:

```
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(intent.getData(), Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

But I know [Android 11 limits to 512](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/06/13/count-your-saf-uri-permission-grants.html) the permissions that you can persist.
So I thought I could use  the flag [Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION) to grant access to files whose uri has a prefix match thus reducing the number of persisted uri permissions.

But I have no clue on how to use this flag. The way I used it, I can't get read access to the files with a prefix match.

So my question is:

**How the flag Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION is supposed to be used?**

Comment: You better start to remove all flags from your intent as they do not make sense there.

Comment: Why do you want >600 if 128 and 512 are the limits? And why yet store in a database where you can always determine them without?

Comment: If you want to do something with that prefix flag then while taking the permission i would say. But never done do so...

Comment: Thank you for CommonsWare blog link. I was unaware of this limitation.

Comment: @blackapps, then what are the purpose of these flags?

Comment: You can use them in for example onActivityResult to take persistable uri permissions (as you do, so why ask?). And use them with ACTION_VIEW to serve a readable file.

Comment: @blackapps you mean like this: getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(intent.getData(), Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)? Because if I do like this: takePersistableUriPermission(intent.getData(), Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION) it gives an error!

Comment: Is it intentionally that you do not post complete code (in your post, not in a commenr) and not mention the error?